# Attributed string in swift label

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Is it possible to use attributed string to set below text on label-

> marks/total:m/t (Blue Color)
>
> position:p (red Color on next line)

Where **m**,**t** and **p** are also variable. I want to show

> **position:p**
> in different color.

Basically I don't want to use multiple variables and use all features of attributed string.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Rashwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this (see comments for explanations):

```
// create your variables, the length does not matter since this is a dynamic solution
let p = "1234"
let m = "30"
let t = "23"

// Create the string
let str = "marks/total:\(m)/\(t)\nposition:\(p)"

// Create the NSMutableAttributedString
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)

// Find the range of position in your string
if let range = str.range(of: "position") {
    // get start and end position for your word "position"
    let start = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
    let end = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)

    // Color position
    attrStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location: start, length: end - start))
}

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100))
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.attributedText = attrStr
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

This will get you:
[image]